# What do you call a fake abbreviation?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a fake abbreviation? Like saying that CNN stands for Crap News Network instead of Cable News Network. What do you call it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "fake abbreviation". Because when you write Crap News Network, it is not an abbreviation. Also, this question is not about English, so I vote to close it.

Comment: That's called **misinterpretation**.

Comment: What do you call it, in your language?  What is the literal translation of that in English?

Comment: Parody might fit.

Comment: A humorous interpretation of the abbreviation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **acronym** is an initialism that forms a pronounceable word, like SCUBA or RADAR or NASA. If someone develops an initialism for the express purpose of spelling a particular word, for example the USA PATRIOT Act,<sup>1</sup> that is called a **backronym** (backwards acronym).

"CNN" is only an abbreviation, not an acronym, because "CNN" is not a pronounceable word. But you might be able to stretch the definition and say that "Crap News Network" is a backronym for CNN.

---

<sup>1</sup>Uniting and Strengthening America by Providing Appropriate Tools Required to Intercept and Obstruct Terrorism Act